# Correct PPA to install Python 3 on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04

Tags: python, ppa, repository, python3, official-repositories

For Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 I need to install python 3. Currently 3.9.**5** as I wrote this post. I watched some videos on youtube and read some tutorials. There are two different approaches

**One**

```
sudo apt install python3 [python-pip]`
```

**Two**

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.9
```

The situation is that about [“deadsnakes” team](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes) says:

- Team for maintaining **unofficial** Python packages for different releases of Ubuntu.

And in [ppa:deadsnakes - New Python Versions](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) says:

```
This PPA contains more recent Python versions packaged for Ubuntu.

Disclaimer: there's no guarantee of timely updates in case of security problems or other issues. 
If you want to use them in a security-or-otherwise-critical environment (say, on a production server),
you do so at your own risk.

Update Note
===========
Please use this repository instead of ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes.
```

**Observation:** The tutorials and videos based on `ppa:deadsnakes` are <1 year ago (they are not neither very old nor outdated) and even are for Ubuntu 20.04 and works. **Question 1**: When could be mandatory take the `ppa:deadsnakes` approach?

So thinking in have *always* the latest, stable and secure python installed. **Question 2**: what approach is the correct?

I am not sure, but seems there is no an official guide to install Python (latest version 3.9.5) on Ubuntu. **Question 3**: Is there an official (latest-stable-secure) Python repository for PPA?.

**For future**

So if Python at https://www.python.org/ releases the 3.9.**6** version, then if `sudo apt update upgrade` is executed that new release must be installed

Comment: Why do you need 3.9? Whatever you do, do not change default python version that comes with Ubuntu version you have.

Comment: The latest release is expected to have many bugs fixed and new features and improved performance.

Comment: If the *bugs* are security fixes; they are back-ported to the version that comes with Ubuntu (if's more work to backport than provide a later version; you'll get a newer version instead which explains why versions can be upgraded sometimes).  New features are not back-ported; but if you want the latest programs/features you should be using the latest release (`3.9.4-1` currently) and not using latest-2 * & latest-7 releases.

Comment: No *personal package archive* (PPA) is official for Ubuntu; they are *testing* only (or 3rd party) as *stable* is found in official Ubuntu repositories. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: @guiverc your latest comment is confuse, which is stable?

Comment: @oldfred and @guiverc, consider to read the `For future` block added.

Comment: PPAs are *personal package archives* (what PPA name is) and are **not** by definition *stable* but intended for **unofficial 3rd party packages** OR for use in *testing* software.  No PPA is ever official as that's what Ubuntu repositories are for  (or the Snap Store) - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu    **Ubuntu repositories** 'main' 'restricted' 'universe' and 'multiverse' are **stable**.

Comment: Thanks, so the `sudo apt install python3 [python-pip]` is the correct approach.